# sqlmap - Dump multiple columns at once?

Tags: mysql

I'm playing around with sqlmap, and I'm having a little trouble dumping database columns.

I can dump all of them at once which is great, but this database has thousands of users and dumping every column would take over a day, whereas dumping columns individually only takes about 15 minutes. The only problem with this is that all the data is dumped from A-Z, which means I have no idea which hash is for which user.

Is there a way of dumping multiple columns (but not all) at once to prevent them being mixed up?

Cheers!

Comment: Don't deface your posts.

Answer (score 1):

The switch you're looking for here is -C which specified the columns to be dumped from a target table (which you specify with -T).  More info is [here](https://github.com/sqlmapproject/sqlmap/wiki/Usage)

Comment: I have been using -C to dump columns individually, but what I'd like to do is choose say.. 3 or 4 columns and dump only them. Rather than dumping all 20 or however many there are.

Are you able to do that using -C?

Comment: yep, IIRC you just specify the columns you're interested in with a comma to separate them...

Comment: maybe this helps ?! you can dump from column 5 to 10 using option `--start=5 --stop=10`